# Unable to decode a Base64 encoded object

Tags: java, object, salesforce, base64, decode

I am using salesforce api to get a salesforce document in my local machine. The document is base64 encoded. It is returned as an Object type. When I try to decode it to save it on my local machine, it gives an 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -84' error. I know it occurs when we try to access an non-existent index on an array but I am not doing that here. I am using commons library.

Could anyone of you help me or suggest a better way to decode and store the file at my local machine.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; //and other imports
private void querySample() {
    try {
        // Set query batch size
        partnerConnection.setQueryOptions(250);

        // SOQL query to use
        String soqlQuery = "SELECT Name, Body, BodyLength FROM Document LIMIT 1";
        // Make the query call and get the query results
        QueryResult qr = partnerConnection.query(soqlQuery);

        boolean done = false;
        SObject document;
        Object docName;
        Object docBody;
        Object bodyLength;
        byte[] encoded;
        byte[] decoded;
        int loopCount = 0;
        // Loop through the batches of returned results
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("Records in results set " + loopCount++
                    + " - ");
            SObject[] records = qr.getRecords();
            // Process the query results
            for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                document = records[i];
                docName = document.getField("Name");
                docBody = document.getField("Body");            //Body is base 64
                bodyLength = document.getField("BodyLength");

                encoded = serialize(docBody);
                Integer size = Integer.parseInt((String) bodyLength);

                decoded = new byte[size];   

                decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded); //<-- Getting error here

                String path = "D:\\myImage.png";
                OutputStream out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(path));
                out1.write(decoded);

            }
            if (qr.isDone()) {
                done = true;
            } else {
                qr =   partnerConnection.queryMore(qr.getQueryLocator());
            }

        }
    } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("\nQuery execution completed.");

}

public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject(obj);
    return b.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide the stacktrace. Or even the data you are decoding?

Comment: at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isBase64(Base64.java:137)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.discardNonBase64(Base64.java:478)
 at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:374)
 at SFTPMain.querySample(SFTPMain.java:115)
 at SFTPMain.main(SFTPMain.java:32)

Comment: What's the deal with the serialize call there?  Why not just Base64 decode the docBody itself?